# How to make a .htaccess redirect with header and folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would the .htaccess code look like that redirects

http://www.example.com/folder 
to 
http://example.com/folder?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `redirect with header and folders`?

Comment: Good question! :) It was difficult to formulate the title so it would be accepted as a valid title... In the text you have the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! :) But what about the RewriteRules below, would this stop them from executing something important?

Comment: No it won't affect any rule below it.

Comment: Sure will! But I just found out that it only works in Google Chrome. when opening the site in Internet Explorer it redirects back to the domain root when using both urls.  :/

Comment: It will work in IE also, just clear your browser cache in IE.

Comment: Now it works in IE too, after trying "In Private mode"! But I tried to clear the cashe 10 times without any effect!!! Isn't this the way to clear cache in IE??? Tools - Internet options - Delete - Mark all options but Form Data and Password and click delete.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do what you need, i put comments in front of the lines to show what they do:

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On

# set the rewrite base (optional)
RewriteBase /

# if the http host has something in front of the domain name
# capture what is written after the domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]

# if the above is true forward user with 301 redirect to the domain name without 
# www or anything in front and add what we captured in the line above
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I added some comments

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. Maybe because I didn't gave you the whole picture. Here is the whole .htaccess file. Would you have a look at it please (cant post it here)? netway.se/projects/issue255.htm